# pageYOffset doesn't change my style property

Tags: javascript

I've tried many combinations of this code and nothing works correctlly. I've also tried scrollTop. Just look at my js code and tell me what is wrong with it.

```
 <header>
    <div class="nav" id="nav">

           <div class="navRow" id="navRow">

            <div class="navBrand" id="brand"><a href="#"><img src="img/logo-light.png" alt="Snow" height="35"></a></div>
            <div class="navLinks">
            <div class="navItem"><a href="#">About</a></div>
            <div class="navItem"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
            <div class="navItem"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></div>
            <div class="navItem"><a href="#">Blog</a></div>
            <div class="navItem"><a href="#">Wordpress Theme</a></div>
           </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</header>


<script>
var yPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
    if (yPos > 50 || document.body.pageYOffset > 50) {
        nav.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    else {
        nav.style.backgroundColor = "none";
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs only once when page loads. I suppose you want it to run on every scroll event:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // ... your code here
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it was that and the overflow-x of body